# JS files doesn't work correctly in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

As I've mentioned in the title, I'm having some problems with my js files.
I've tested the scripts in the HTML template and works fine, but when I put them into the `functions.php` file there are some scripts that doesn't work as they should.

Here the `functions.php` file:

```
<?php
function load_stylesheets(){
 /************/
}

function add_js(){
    wp_register_script('jquery-min', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-min');
    wp_register_script('jquery-migrate', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-migrate');
    wp_register_script('popper', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/popper/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('popper');
    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');
    wp_register_script('easing', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/easing/easing.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('easing');
    wp_register_script('jquery.waypoints', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/counterup/jquery.waypoints.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.waypoints');
    wp_register_script('jquery.counterup', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/counterup/jquery.counterup.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.counterup');
    wp_register_script('carousel', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('carousel');
    wp_register_script('lightbox', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/lightbox/js/lightbox.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('lightbox');
    wp_register_script('typed', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/typed/typed.min.js', array('jquery'), 2, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('typed');
    wp_register_script('contactform', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/contactform.js', array('jquery'), 3, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('contactform');
    wp_register_script('main', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/main.js', array('jquery'), 3, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('main');
}
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "load_stylesheets", "add_js", 999);
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work as they should"? Are they loading or not?

Comment: There's no errors reported in the logs, so I think that they're loaded correctly, but some functionalities doesn't work, for instance, the smooth js-scrolling

Comment: PD: The main script that performs the smooth scrolling works fine in the html-template version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hook into [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/) and call multiple functions like that:

```php
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "load_stylesheets", "add_js", 999);
```

[`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) accepts these four parameters:

> - `$tag` *(string) (Required)* The name of the action to which the `$function_to_add` is hooked.
> - `$function_to_add` (callable) (Required) The name of the function you wish to be called.
> - `$priority` *(int) (Optional)* Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>     *Default value: 10*
> - `$accepted_args` *(int) (Optional)* The number of arguments the function accepts.
>     *Default value: 1*

So, to add both your stylesheets and scripts you'll have to do:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets', 999 );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_js', 999 );
```

Comment: @JeanLouis Glad it worked, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please consider marking it as accepted :)